# Include helper not works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

I'm trying to include some helpers to my test but I can't  make that it works.
I got the following error:

```rb
/home/edu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/features/customers_spec.rb ./spec/features/login_spec.rb ./spec/features/products_spec.rb ./spec/features/suppliers_spec.rb
        /home/edu/Desktop/rails_proyects/gg/spec/support/features.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant MyHelp (NameError)
          from /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@gg/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core.rb:120:in `configure'
          from /home/edu/Desktop/rails_proyects/gg/spec/support/features.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

I have this:

```rb
# spec/support/features/session_helper.rb
module MyHelp
  module SessionHelpers
    ...
    def sign_in
      ...
    end
  end
end

# spec/support/features.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include MyHelp::SessionHelpers, type: :feature
end
```

I'm using it here:

```rb
# spec/features/login_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

feature "Login" do
  scenario "with valid credentials" do
    user = create(:user)
    sign_in user.email, user.password
    page.should have_content(I18n.t('layouts.header.exit', locale: 'es'))
  end
end
```

I'm using:

```
rspec (2.14.1)
rspec-core (2.14.6, 2.14.5) 
rspec-expectations (2.14.3, 2.14.2) 
rspec-mocks (2.14.4, 2.14.3) 
rspec-rails (2.14.0)

ruby 1.9.3p392 
rails 3.2.13
```

Can someone help me with this?
thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just need to require the new helper before you try to use it in `spec/support/features.rb`

```
require Rails.root.join('spec/support/features/session_helper')
```

Also, it's best practice to have your class/module match the file name, so either the file should be pluralized, or the helper singularized.